# How to customize Volusion Templates without access to .ASP files

Tags: asp.net, templates, customization, volusion

We had a client ask us to redisign their Volusion site. I understand that Volusion gives you access to, *basically*, 1 main HTML file and a small handfull of CSS files. But, if I understand correctly, they do NOT give you access to edit the .ASP files for the site/template.

Beyond simple CSS changes, How do you create your own custom Volusion Template without access to .ASP files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have access to the code that makes up the product or category content areas for example.
You are able to edit the primary template (ie template_yourstore.htm) and its corresponding CSS. If you want to go further than this you are dependent on javascript to makes changes client-side.

To be totally clear, you can use asp but only on your own asp pages. You cannot change Volusion's code.